# Building symbolic link shared library in a shared folder of VirtualBox

Tags: c++, linux, cmake, virtual-machine, virtualbox

I am now building a C++ library in Windows and Linux. For windows I am now using Visual Studio for development, and for Linux I am now using Ubuntu via Virtual Box. In order to make develop much easier, I shared the folder of the project in Windows with Linux via the shared folder function of Virtual Box. I compile and run the project in Windows first and if it succeeds I will compile it in Linux. This is made possible thanks to CMake. The problem I have is that if the shared library to be built is a symbolic link one it cannot be compiled in Linux as [this page suggests](http://redmine.webtoolkit.eu/boards/2/topics/5246). If it is not a symbolic one, it is fine. Then my questions are as follows:

- Is symbolic link property important for a library in Linux?
- Are there some solutions that can build the symbolic link library successfully in shared folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Configuring your project outside of shared folder may help.

```
cd ~
mkdir build
cd build
cmake /path/to/mounted/shared/folder
make
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that the shared folder's permissions are set to not allow symbolic links by default. You can enable them in a few easy steps.

1. Shut down the virtual machine.
2. Note your machine name at `Machine > Settings > General > Name`
3. Note your shared folder name at `Machine > Settings > Shared Folders`
4. Find your VirtualBox root directory and execute the following command.
   `VBoxManage setextradata "<machine name>" VBoxInternal2/SharedFoldersEnableSymlinksCreate/<shared folder name> 1`
5. Start up the virtual machine and the shared folder will now allow symbolic links.